# Compute direction of gravity vector

Tags: gps, geolocation, physics, geo

As I understand to compute vector of gravity not saficient to compute normal to elipsoid, but we need to computer normal to [geoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid)?

But how to compute normal to geoid, how geoid is defined?
Wiki article say that it's represented by Spherical harmonics.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Comment: @Pang, Are you sure? The problem is that you do not understand the question, and think it is not software development related. There is more in SW than simple for loops, In doubt do not vote for close. Do you realy think that such an irregular structure like a geoid can be hand calculated? Of course this will be solved with software.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the know anything about geoids to compute the vector of gravity.

Newtonian gravity is a monopole force, so it acts between the centers of mass of the two objects.  The shapes of the objects don't matter at all.  Let's assume you have two objects 1 and 2 and the coordinates of the object's centers of mass are:
r_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1) and
r_2 = (x_2,y_2,z_2)

The direction of gravitational force on object 1 from object 2 is then simply the difference between the vectors (gravity is always attractive):
r = r_2 - r_1= (x_2 - x_1,y_2 - y1,z_2 - z_1)

If object 1 is something sitting on the surface of Earth and you are looking for the normal force caused by the Earth's surface pushing back on the bottom of object 1, that normal force vector **is** given by the normal to the surface at that point.

Comment: This doesn't answer to the question. It is about geoid and the way to compute its normal vector.

Comment: He wants to "compute vector of gravity" and thinks he has to use the geoid to do so.  That premise is incorrect.

Comment: You should add your comment to your answer.